Cant manage to download a summary for Dirichlet Regression model in R and get error message
Good day,
An example of my data:

I ran the following codes in R:
DR_WCcomp <- read.csv("C:/Users/ottoa/Desktop/Personal Documentation/Analysis/data/DR_WCcomp.csv")
attach(DR_WCcomp)
View(DR_WCcomp)
    library (DirichletReg)
    head(DR_WCcomp)
    WC <- DR_data(DR_WCcomp[, 7:11])
    WC1 <- DirichReg(WC ~ DDH, DR_WCcomp, model = "alternative") 
    WC2 <- DirichReg(WC ~ DBH + H, DR_WCcomp, model = "alternative") 
    WC3 <- DirichReg(WC ~ DBH, DR_WCcomp, model = "alternative") 
    anova(WC1, WC2, WC3)
    summary(WC2)
    predict(WC2)

And get the error message:
Error in summary.DirichletRegModel(WC2) :
Optimization did not converge in 149 + 1 iterations and exited with code 8
When I run the following code:
WC2 <- DirichReg(BM ~ DBH + H, data = DR_WCcomp, model = "alternative", control = list(interlim = 3000, tol1 = 1e-9, tol2 = 1e-9, maxit = 6000))
summary(WC2)

I get the message:
Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula, lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs, data = data,  :
variable lengths differ (found for 'DBH')
Then, I did some trouble shooting with the following:
sum(is.na(DR_WCcomp$DBH))
sum(is.na(DR_WCcomp$H))
sum(is.na(DR_WCcomp$Stem))
sum(is.na(DR_WCcomp$Bark))
sum(is.na(DR_WCcomp$Needle))
sum(is.na(DR_WCcomp$Branch))
sum(is.na(DR_WCcomp$Cone))

but there were no missing values for any of the columns.
Also, the command did not result in anything out of the ordinary that I could detect:
str(DR_WCcomp) 


The predict(WC2) command seems to be working fine but I cant get a summary() or print() of WC2 to get the parameters of the models.
Your assistance with the trouble shooting will be much appreciated.
Cheers

There are a couple of ideas here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75290168/r-dirichreg-error-in-summary-dirichletregmodel-optimization-did-not-converge-in

Thanks Andrew, I saw that post. It seems like the convergence code above helped to solve the issue, but then it went back to  "Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula, lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs, data = data, : variable lengths differ (found for 'DBH')" So, this seems to be the outstanding issue

It is hard to help any further without a reproducible example. I see that you use BM as a dependent variable, but this is not defined anywhere. Also, the documentation for DirichReg says that the dependent variable should be part of the dataframe. So you perhaps need DR_WCcomp$WC <- DR_data(DR_WCcomp[, 7:11]) rather than having WC as a separate variable.

@AndrewGustar. Thank you so much! I have made a typo with BM and have changed it to WC. The variable length error disappeared and returned the "Optimization did not converge in 149 + 1 iterations and exited with code 8" error. I increased the tolerance and maxit values in the following equation WC2 <- DirichReg(WC ~ DBH + H, data = DR_WCcomp, model = "alternative", control = list(interlim = 6000, tol1 = 2e-9, tol2 = 2e-9, maxit = 9000))
summary(WC2) but still get the same optimization error as above. Should I increase the values even more?

It is worth a try, just to see if that is the problem. Also, did you try the suggestion about putting WC within the dataframe?

@AndrewGustar. Yes, I have changed that and that solved the variable length error with changing BM to WC.
